# GPS tracker with jQuery mobile, PhoneGap and Google Maps

Tags: android, jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've developed a jQuery Mobile app with PhoneGap for Android. Now, I need a GPS Tracker. I want to get the position of the user and compare it with some coordinates from a database.

I would like to know, if this approach is ok, if I should change something and how I can show a message only one time?

- The app should check the position each 20 seconds
- If the user is near the target (50 meter), he should get a message (but only once)

---

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", function( event ) {

function userDistance() {

    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    var watchID = null;

    // PhoneGap is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        // Update every 10 seconds
        var options = { frequency: 10000 };
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    function onSuccess(position) {

        // user location
        var loc1 = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        // target location 
        $.getJSON("http://server:8080/getCoords", function(data) {
            var loc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].latitude, data[0].longitude);

            // distance
            var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween (loc1, loc2);

            if (distance < 50) {    
                alert("target arrived");
            }
        });

    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    function onError(error) {

    }

    // watching position every 20s
    setTimeout(userDistance, 20000);
}

userDistance();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

W/o spoon feeding the code, the logic is simple.

1) Create a variable in the global/root notified=0. This variable will tell your function if the user has been notified or not
2) in your alert routine, add the following code

```
if (distance < 50 and **notified==0**) {    
            **notified=1;** // tells your app that the user has been notified already, and wont alert again
            alert("target arrived");

        }
```

3) in your CHECK distance routine, add an evaluation for when distance > 50, reset the variable , notified = 0

This logic solves the problems:
1) Notify the user only once when he/she is in the target distance/radius of the map (50m)
2) If the user leaves the target radius, he will be notified again, once, when he enters the radius.

Hope this helps